# Delay startup of routing logic in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I am working on a SPA which defines many routes using angulars [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Before any routing occurs, I want to execute some *asynchronous* actions, especially fetching a list of localized strings used in the whole application. I therefore want to delay the routing until all those actions (which are actually promises) were resolved. If any is rejected, the application should stop and show a generic error message.

I could return some `ensureInitialized()` promise from the `resolve` parameter of the route definition, but this would require me to do it for all possible routes and lead to code duplication.

Is there any better way to achieve this? What would you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to bootstrap it manually with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: good idea, but as I am using few angular-based components (ngResource, $q, global constants like service endpoints, common services) for the initial loading, this might be problematic and would require few code changes.